# Powershell Center Excel Cell Text

Tags: excel, powershell

When I set the last line of code equal to **$xlCenter** I receive an error stating "Unable to set the horizontal alignment of the range class."

But if I set the last line equal to **-4108** without referencing the variable it works.

I am just curious as to why this happens and if there is a way to resolve it. It would be useful to be able to store all the values I would use for editing into variables at the beginning of my script and not have to lookup/memorize them all.

**Produces an Error:**

```
$xlCenter = -4108 
$Excel = New-object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $false
$Filepath = "PATH HERE"
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($Filepath)
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets(1)
$Worksheet.Range("C1").HorizontalAlignment = $xlCenter
```

**Works Properly:**

```
$Worksheet.Range("C1").HorizontalAlignment = -4108
```

Comment: Can't repro based on what you've provided.

Comment: I figured it out. For some reason, I only get the error when I run the code in the Powershell Integrated Console in Visual Studio instead of the default Powershell terminal.